# C Characters per line indentation based on user input

Tags: c, linked-list, counter

I'm working on a C project that will indent a line based on the number of chars per line the user specifies. I'm having trouble with how to chose when to start the next line, as it can't break up a word between 2 lines.
The way it should work is as follows
1) Check the number of words that can go in the line using wordPerLine giving it a copy of the list
2) Add words until it reaches the max words for that line
3) After it reaches the max words, start a new line and continue until the end of the list is reached.

It's saying "Segment fault (Core dumped)". If there is any help you can give me, I'd very much appreciate it.

This is my word per line function:

```
  int wordPerLine(int size,LISTNODEPTR temp){
   int chars=0;
   int words=0;
   int spaces=0;
   while(temp!=NULL && (chars+spaces)<size){
       if(!isspace(temp->data)) {
           chars++;
           temp=temp->nextPtr;
       } else {
           words++;
           chars++;
           spaces=words-1;
           temp=temp->nextPtr;
       }
   }
   return words;
}
```

My list structure:

```
struct listNode {  /* self-referential structure */
 char data;
 struct listNode *nextPtr;
};
```

And the print function I'm trying to put everything together with

```
void printList(LISTNODEPTR currentPtr, int spaces)
{
 //Temp variable to avoid moving the actual pointer in the length       function
LISTNODEPTR temp = currentPtr;
int x=0;
int remaining=0;
int chars=0;
int wordsAvail=0;
int wordsUsed=0;
if (currentPtr == NULL)
  printf("Empty String.\n\n");
else {

    //Checks if the list is at the end and exits if TRUE

   while(currentPtr!=NULL){
       wordsAvail=wordsPerLine(spaces,temp);
       for(wordsUsed=0; wordsUsed<=wordsAvail;wordsUsed++) {
           while(!isspace(currentPtr->data)&& currentPtr!=NULL) {
               printf("%c",currentPtr->data);
               currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
               temp=currentPtr;
           }
           wordsUsed++;
           printf(" ");
           while(isspace(currentPtr->data)&& currentPtr!=NULL) {
               currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
               temp=currentPtr;
           }  
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Generally, it would help you to know how to use a core dump.  The dump will tell you where the segmentation fault occurs.  You're debugger will become your best friend. :-)  In this case, I notice in your print function that you set the `currentPtr` in the `!isspace` while loop, and then outside of that loop, you use `currentPtr` without being certain it's not null.  Your issue likely will be on the line `while(isspace(currentPtr->data))`

Comment: [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: using a linked list for "characters in a line" is much too complex. Think about how long a line can be? Assume lines cannot be longer than 1000 characters, so a `char line[1000]` would just hold your lines. Such an array will be much more effective. Analyze your data record: The technical `nextPtr` just holds structural information. On a 64bit Machine your informational / total data size in the list record is at least(without memory alignment) 1 / 9. That is very bad and in the real world it will be even worse actually.

Comment: I'm using an online IDE that doesn't have a debugger :( but I added a null check to the line and it's still giving me the error. I updated the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Segment fault (Core dumped)

is an indication that you attempted to read memory that is outside of your program's allocated RAM.  This typically means you have a pointer in your program which is either initialized (or not initialized) to a value that is outside of your program's allocated RAM, and you have dereferenced it (asked for the value at the pointer's stored address).

Your program has very few pointers.  Let's look at them

```
currentPointer
```

is used in

```
while(!isspace(currentPtr->data)&& currentPtr!=NULL) {
```

which checks to see if it is `NULL`, but only after it attempts to get the data and pass it to `isspace(...)`.

I think you might want to check to see if currentPtr is `NULL` before attempting to dereference it, like so

```
while(currentPtr!=NUll && !isspace(currentPtr->data)) {
```